# Sounds design with video seq and DAW

Tags: audio, daw, video

What procedure should I use if I have video clips from a game (animations/cut scenes) and I need to precisely set every sound in it to the ms.

For example, I have a sequence with starting monitors and different lights, but I can't set it precisely because I cant run video in a player and designed sounds in DAW at the same time.

I can do that perfectly in Adobe Premiere, but this lacks DAW presets and settings needed for each sound.

I can export files from DAW with desired effects, but when I decide to tweak them, I have to export them again, which is very upsetting.

How do you guys doing such things? Any advice for a DAW/plugin which can run also a video synchronized with sounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't do that in the DAW you have right now, it's not the right one to use. The taste differs here which one's the best for any given application, and there are not really any rights and wrongs as long as you can work with it...provided you dont't have to mind any particular standards that some doesn't support. Some like Pro Tools, some (like me) like Nuendo. Others like Pyramix, Cubase, Logic or maybe Audition. They all have their own different strengths and weaknesses, as well as different learningcurves, so you have to find one that fits you.

The best way I can see, is if you can get demo-versions of the different programs, and figure them out from there. If you can't then figure out what you think you need, and read up on them. If you're still unsure from there, two programs tend to stand out over the others in terms of standards - Pro Tools - a de facto standard in most studios, and Nuendo - often favored by people who, in some cases, think Pro Tools is too expensive and simply not worth it, and in other cases, just like it better!

Comment: Cubase is fine if you have a single linear video to work on [it can't run 2 videos at once, though it can run them contiguously], though without some of the higher-end functionality of Nuendo - cheaper too